# MySQL date repeat

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

In one of my web application ( in PHP and MySQL ) there is a event reminder for users. User can add the next reminder date and also put the repeat interval ( ie Only Once, 3 months, 6 months and yearly ). Saving that in table like

```
id      |    emp_id      |    alert_date         |   repeat_interval
--------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------
1       |      124       |  2014-05-02 00:00:00  |     3
--------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------
2       |      123       |  2014-05-02 00:00:00  |     12
--------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------
3       |      122       |  2014-02-02 00:00:00  |     6
--------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------
4       |      121       |  2014-07-02 00:00:00  |     0
--------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------
5       |      124       |  2014-05-02 00:00:00  |     6
--------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------
6       |      125       |  2014-08-02 00:00:00  |     6
--------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------
7       |      126       |  2014-06-02 00:00:00  |     12
--------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------
8       |      127       |  2014-05-02 00:00:00  |     3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The repeat_interval having the value as

```
0 - One time event
3 - Every 3 months
6 - Every 6 months
12 - Yearly
```

Now I have a "cronjob" running every morning, searching for events and send alerts to users. I have the following MySQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM alerts as al 
WHERE date(al.alert_date) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

This will return the tmrw's alerts and I can send mail with this. But my question is how to take these intervals also ?

ie if the alert_date is 01-05-2013 and set repeat for 3 months then need to send mail on
01-05-2013 and the intervals of 3 months

Actually is this the correct way for this purpose ? Or I need to alter the tables ?

Can any one give me an idea ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to send an email `every day for 3 months` from `alert_date` or `on the alert_date` and then again `3 months after the alert_date`.

Comment: Since the column is name repeat_*interval*, I think it's safe to assume that is a repetetive occurence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo can just update the alert_date with the next date it is supposed to be alerted on.
So every time the cronjob is executed, update all alerts that have repeat_interval != 0, with alert_date + repeat_interval number of months. I guess you can use the DATE_ADD() function to just att months:

```
UPDATE alerts SET alert_date = DATE_ADD(alert_date, INTERVAL repeat_interval MONTHS) WHERE repeat_interval != 0
```

If you need to store the original date, just create an extra column, next_alert, and update that date as such.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to add another column (for example `next_alert`) into your database which will tell you, when next event occurs.

Then in your cron script you will simply checks if `next_alert` date matches current date and if yes, adjust `next_alert` to `next_alert + repeat_interval` of course use specific sql function to add months to date

```
DATE_ADD(next_alert, INTERVAL repeat_interval MONTHS)
```

or use PHP methods to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more column next_alert_date which will store next date on which alert will be send and update the column value to next alert date as per the interval set and you can use the same cron with it also. Adding one more column will help you in tracking when it was started also that is the current alert_date column you have.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add any fields like next_alert or next_date etc. You can find the reminders simply from below code.

**Just create a function and pass the date in that function. The below code will give you result for that date.**

```
CREATE TABLE `reminder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `startdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `enddate` date NOT NULL,
  `kind` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `reminder`
-- 

INSERT INTO `reminder` (`id`, `title`, `startdate`, `enddate`, `kind`) VALUES 
(1, 'This is reminder', '2015-06-03 19:25:44', '2015-07-21', 'weekly'); 

-- Query data get results for 2015-06-17 from  `reminder` table
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ','2015-06-17',TIME(startdate)) AS ReminderDateTime, title
  FROM reminder  
  WHERE IF(
    kind='daily',
    ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-06-17') -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(startdate))) % (1*24*60*60)=0)  ,
    IF(
      kind='weekly',
      ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-06-17') -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(startdate))) % (7*24*60*60)=0)  ,
      IF(
        kind='monthly',
        DAYOFMONTH('2015-06-17')=DAYOFMONTH(startdate),             
        IF(
          kind='quarterly',
          ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-06-17') -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(startdate))) % (91*24*60*60)=0) ,
          IF(
            kind='yearly',
            DAYOFYEAR('2015-06-17')=DAYOFYEAR(startdate), 
            IF(
              kind='',
              startdate,
              '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
            )
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
     )
    ) AND DATE(startdate) <='2015-06-17' AND IF(enddate<>'0000-00-00',enddate>='2015-06-17','1') ORDER BY ReminderDateTime ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the answer by Ritesh to add semi-annual and make the quarterly tasks repeat on the same day and not 91 days and the dates will vary in few quarters.

**Create table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_events;  
CREATE TABLE tbl_events (  
  user int(11) NOT NULL,  
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  startdate datetime NOT NULL,  
  enddate date NOT NULL,  
  kind varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Add data to table**

```
INSERT INTO tbl_events VALUES   
('1','1','This is daily reminder','2017-04-24 00:00:00','2020-12-31','daily'),  
('1','2','This is weekly reminder','2017-04-24 00:00:00','2020-12-31','weekly'),  
('1','3','This is monthly reminder','2017-04-24 00:00:00','2020-12-31','monthly'), 
('1','4','This is quarterly reminder','2017-04-24 00:00:00','2020-12-31','quarterly'),  
('1','5','This is yearly reminder','2017-04-24 00:00:00','2020-12-31','yearly');
```

**Query data get results for 2017-10-23 from  tbl_events table**

```
SELECT user, '2017-10-23' AS Date, title  
  FROM tbl_events    
  WHERE IF(  
kind='daily',  
    ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-10-23') -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(startdate))) % (1*24*60*60)=0)  ,  
    IF(  
      kind='weekly',  
      ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-10-23') -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(startdate))) % (7*24*60*60)=0)  ,  
      IF(  
        kind='monthly',  
        DAYOFMONTH('2017-10-23')=DAYOFMONTH(startdate),   
        IF(  
          kind='quarterly',  
            DAYOFMONTH('2017-10-23')=DAYOFMONTH(startdate) AND abs(MONTH('2017-10-24')-MONTH(startdate))%3=0,  
          IF(  
          kind='semiannual',  
            DAYOFMONTH('2017-10-23')=DAYOFMONTH(startdate) AND abs(MONTH('2017-10-24')-MONTH(startdate))%6=0,  
              IF(  
                kind='yearly',  
                DAYOFYEAR('2017-10-23')=DAYOFYEAR(startdate),   
                IF(  
                  kind='',  
                  startdate,  
                  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'  
                )  
              )   
          )  
        )   
      )   
     )  
    ) AND DATE(startdate) <='2017-10-23' AND IF(enddate<>'0000-00-00',enddate>='2017-10-23','1') ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Comment: Also would be best to add an option if the date is after 28th for monthly, quaterly and semi-annually reminder. So add an option if it is after 28th whether the reminder needs to be on last day of month or not if is does not have those many days etc.